# Translate user input into date / dateTime

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I was wondering if there is any node.js module or any other library that translates English user input into a date with a time portion. So for example (now: 2018/10/25 14:00)

```
'now' > 2018/10/25 14:00
'16:00' > 2018/10/25 16:00
'in one hour' > 2018/10/25 15:00
'tomorrow' > 2018/10/26 14:00
'tomorrow at 15:00' > 2018/10/25 15:00
'day after tomorrow' > 2018/10/27 14:00
'christmas day' > 2018/12/25 00:00
```

Comment: Something like https://momentjs.com ?

Comment: moment('tomorrow').format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm') > 0NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN

Comment: If you want to achieve something like this, then it is not as simple as using a node module because possibilities could be endless. It then boils down to typical problem of 'Natural Language Understanding' to translate queries into machine readable entities.

Comment: I understand it is difficult, but is is a fairly enclosed (and common) scope, since it only concerns dates. I was hoping there was something out there.

Comment: I don't know it but it seems to be what you are looking for https://github.com/wanasit/chrono